# Оптимальный запрос

Tags: mysql

Есть конкретный вопрос.
Имеется таблица новостей `posts`, есть поле `area_id`
`area_id` может быть например от 1 до 50
Задача:
Если есть возможность одним запросом, если нет, наиболее оптимальным способом выбрать из базы по 10 записей для каждой `area_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY area_id ORDER BY id) AS rn
              FROM posts )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE rn <= 10
```

Ну или `ORDER BY RAND()`.

---

> А если расширить вопрос и нужно выбрать разное количество записей, например area_id = 1 10 штук, area_id = 2 30 штук – sepgg

```sql
WITH cte AS ( SELECT *, 
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY area_id ORDER BY id) AS rn
              FROM posts ), 
     cnt AS ( SELECT 1 area_id, 10 amount UNION ALL
              SELECT 2, 30 UNION ALL
              ... )
SELECT *
FROM cte
JOIN cnt USING (area_id)
WHERE cte.rn <= cnt.amount
```

Comment: А если расширить вопрос и нужно выбрать разное количество записей, например area_id = 1 10 штук, area_id = 2 30 штук

Comment: @sepgg Добавил.